# Optimize Genetic Neural Network resolving Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, tic-tac-toe

I have programmed in Python a Neural Network with the following structure:

- **9 input neurons**, one for each possible space in the 3x3 grid of the game. Their value will be: 
  +1 (ai's move), -1 (opponent's move), 0 (if empty)
- **9** neurons in the **hidden layer**
- **9 output neurons**, one for each possible move. I select the one with the highest value. If that move is illegal I'll consider the following highest, and so on.

I have added bias to allow the initial move, when every input is set to 0.
So I have two weight matrices, **W1** (between input and hidden) and **W2** (between hidden and output), both **10x9**.

I have set a genetic algorithm in order to find their best values. 
I use **10 as popoulation size**. Every neural net of the population will battle **100 opponent neural nets**, with random weights, which do not evolve. Every 50 generations I regenerate all their weights. The **fitness** value for each neural net is valued like this: *2*(n. of wins) + (n. of draws) - 4*(n. of losses)*
I then select the five best neural nets, and I copy them in the following generation. I also generate five other neural nets by swapping weights and introducing random mutations with 10% probability.

I can see that the fitness value is going up, almost every generation. Every 50, as predictable, it goes down, because of the opponents' change, but then starts rising again. 
After 500 generations, I collected the updated weights, and tried that trained neural network against a new opponent, a program that makes random moves at every turn. I got like 90% wins, 9% draws and 1% losses. However, beating the net is still easy for a human player.

How can i improve the quality of the resulting neural net? Perhaps is needed a bigger number of generations? Or a different fitness function? What can I improve in the selection process?

Comment: so basically you expect to find a reasonable net by completely random changes? This might take a while. Either way - how can you get 9% winning rate vs random? This looks like a bug, you should get 50% win rate in the worst scenario.

Comment: Yep, mainly for demonstration purpose. I don't want to program anything specific about the game, and let the computer figure out the best way to play, in a natural faction.
I'm quite sure the verifying code is ok: when I replace the trained network with a random one I get a win rate around 40-60%, depending on the case.

Comment: Random changes are not "natural", I mean there is no learning involved, but it is not the problem here - as I said, you have a bug somewhere, it is impossible to get so small win rate, unless you omitted something important. Unless this is like 9% win, 9% loss and 80% draw? Then it is just fine

Comment: I found a little bug in the verifying program: basically certain games were considered both wins and draws, with a chance around 1/150. Then I found a major bug in the fitness function: I misplaced a number and I was training the network to lose. I fixed it and now, in 1250 games vs the random opponent, I get 90% wins, 1% losses, 9% draws. However a human player will find still relatively easy to beat it. How can I improve the result? Is it needed more time or a different fitness function?